# Rewrite folder to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain, subdirectory

I want to rewrite all addresses after this
`http://www.mydomain.com/questions/*`
to this
`http://*.mydomain.com/`
for example:
`http://www.mydomain.com/questions/example`
`http://example.mydomain.com/`
Can anyone help me in this issue!?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^questions/([^/]+)/?$ http://$1.mydomain.com/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

Plug this into your .htaccess file and you should be good to go. :)

Comment: First rule is not required and 2nd one should be: `RewriteRule ^questions/([^/]+)/?$ http://$1.mydomain.com/ [NC,R=301,L]`

Comment: Hmm, I get you. Modified.

Comment: thanks, but does not works! i also have enabled wildcard subdomains in my webhost, and added *.mydomain.com in my host subdomain and also my domain dns panel. do you have any tips!?

Comment: Yes you need to add one more line to enable it for non www URLs. I've edited it accordingly. Let me know if it solves the problem.