# Rewrite folder to subdomain with htaccess for cross domain issues

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've followed the instructions in [Rewrite folder to subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463736/rewrite-folder-to-subdomain) and I'm running into a problem

```
RewriteRule ^cdn/([^/]+)/?$ http://cdn.example.com/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

I'm expecting example.com/cdn/... to redirect to cdn.example.com but instead it's redirecting to cdn.example.com/cdn/.. which doesn't help me.

This attempt is to get around cross domain issues. Can anyone let me know how to make it rewrite how I need it, and also if this is likely to solve the video cross domain issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lack $1 at the end of your RewriteRule.
Also you need rules for cdn. subdomain to tell that all your content is in cdn folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRUle ^cdn - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRUle ^(.*)$ cdn/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^cdn/([^/]+)/?$ http://cdn.example.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```