# htaccess to rewrite folder as subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I read another post on SO but it didn't work for me...
I would like to access from https://VALUE.example.com - what is currently available at https://example.com/folder/VALUE/

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^folder/([^/]+)/?$ https://$1.example.com/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

but it didn't work... any idea?

I took this as reference: [Rewrite folder to subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463736/rewrite-folder-to-subdomain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have redefined your code a little bit:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?folder/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ https://$1.example.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

In your second line there wad on `.` to much, so `example.com` (without the www.) could not work. Than you can combine both `RewriteCond`  lines in one. Last but not least, if the original URL have something additional e.g. `https://example.com/folder/VALUE/something-here`  than it could also not work.

One additional remark: The whole thing would only work if on your server mod_rewrite is enabled and you are allowed to use htaccess files (with mod_rewrite), this is not always the case.